# ionic gapi.auth2.init invalid cookiepolicy

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, single-sign-on, google-signin

I added the google sign-in button in my Ionic 3 application.
Although it is working in my local browser (`ionic serve`), fails when it is deployed in a device (`ionic cordova run android --device`).

Exception `gapi.auth2.init invalid cookiepolicy`

The exception is thrown in

```
private initializeGoogleOAuth2() {

    try {

        this.auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
            client_id: this.CLIENT_ID,
            cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin',
        });

    } catch (error) {
        alert('gapi error' + error)

    }
}
```

**EDIT**
In the device
`window.location` is `file:///android_asset/www/index.html`

I read:

> Google API is not supported when using file://